# Is it possible (...how?) to have a single bootabe USB with a choice of OS installs

Tags: usb-flash-drive, bootable-media

Is it possible to have a single bootable USB key with several install images E.g. for Windows 7, 8 and 10, and be able to choose which of these installs to boot?
If so how to set this up on the USB key.
**Clarification:**  I don't want to run different windows from the USB - I just want to run one of the different installers.  I.e I want to boot from the USB and choose to install a particular flavor of windows.

Comment: You are aware that even if you achieved it [which I don't think is possible] each would take about half an hour to boot & then run at similar speeds once booted?

Comment: Install images (as in you are using a single USB to have multiple Windows installer) or you actually want to Boot an OS from the USB? If you want the first one (install images - so you can simply choose and boot a live CD/DVD to install into the system) - then you can use [YUMI](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/). If you actually want to run a full OS from the USB... some Linux variant fully support it, but Windows ... well.. good luck. (Unless Windows To Go is a thing...?)

Comment: @Darius To clarify its the former not the later.  I.e I want a bunch of windows installer ISO so I can easily boot to different windows installers and install that version of windows - all on one USB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, by using a tool that installs Grub or Syslinux on the USB.
This is because Windows by itself does not support it.

Here are some free products that can create a Multiboot USB :

- [WinSetupFromUSB](http://www.winsetupfromusb.com/) - many tutorials available on website

[image: WinSetupFromUSB]

- [XBOOT](https://sites.google.com/site/shamurxboot/)

[image: XBOOT]

- [SARDU](https://www.sarducd.it/)

[image]